# Do event calls stop execution of the mthod that called it until the event is done?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a save system I created that has two events, OnSaving and OnLoading, in my OnDestroy method I'm calling the OnSaving event then after I'm running some code that requires that the game has fully saved, so my question is when an event is called, does the method that called the event wait until all subscribers have finished as if it was calling an event in the save class, or does it continue execution immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All events(like Action and others) are just delegates - “generic methods”. So when the event is invoked, what actually happens is just a call of all subscribers. Event invocation is atomic - all subscribed methods are called in the order they have subscribed. Simplifying all of this - you just calling multiple methods with one.
And yes, after the event invocation all subscribers' complete execution is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question perfectly

Comment: This depends a lot how exactly your app is being closed though .. so regarding the question, yes, this is true, but regarding your use case have in mind that there are situations where `OnDestroy` might not get called e.g. in a crash of when the user force terminates your app

Comment: You might also want to delay the closing via [`Applicstion.wantsToQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-wantsToQuit.html) ;)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but that shouldn't be an issue for my game because OnDestroy only saves the game temporarily for the next scene, if the player wants to permanently save the game they need to do it manually, so it works out